# Memory allocation for objects within objects

Tags: java, performance, object, memory-management, garbage-collection

From what I understand , if Object A has a reference to Object B as its instance variable , then the reference is stored within the space allocated for Object A on the heap. But Object B itself is stored somewhere else on the heap , outside of space allocated for Object A.

Is this understanding accurate ? What are the advantages of doing memory allocation this way (as opposed to having Object B within Object A on the heap) ?

What are the impacts of this (positive or negative) on the performance of Java's garbage collection mechanism (i.e if Object A get destroyed)?

Comment: Imagine two different objects had references to object B. How would you represent that in your proposed scheme?

Comment: i see. it makes sense the way jvm does mem allocation for Object B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the major benefits is independence of the objects - if B was allocated within A, B could only be collected when A was collected.

As separate objects on the heap, B can now be passed and referenced elsewhere, independently of A, and B will have a lifespan of its own.

The Garbage Collector will know when there are no further root references to either object - e.g. even if A is collected, there might still be other references to B which will prolong its lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

`B`s instances might also be created independently, or they could be used as instance fields for other objects, e.g. Object `C`. If you had instances of `B` within `A` or `C`, you would need to "copy" `B`s around, or let `C` refer `A` to get `B` (clearly not a good idea).

So objects have their own allocation space and, when they need to refer to specific instance of other objects, they just store a "pointer" to their location instead.

Also, following your example, if you have the following code:

```
class A {
    private B myB = new B();

    public B getB() { return this.myB; }
}
```

and some code, say from Object C, calls `B myB = myA.getB();`, then you would not want to tie `C`'s instance to `A`'s. If `A` gets GC'd `C` can still keep its `B` just fine. This is because `B` is not coupled (memory-wise) to `A` or anything else.

Finally, and related to the last point, remember that GC is based on an object graph, and only unreachable nodes are collected. This is simplified greatly by `A`s, `B`s and `C`s being independent nodes (vertexes) and their references the connecting arrows (edges) in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

What you propose ("Objects" baked in the memory of their parent object) will be covered by [value types](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html). See also http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169